# How to DrawImage without gradation

Tags: c#, .net

I have following 3 images and want to use them to draw a background of my application.
[image: Top Binder]
[image: Center Binder]
[image: Bottom Binder]

But when I draw it by enlarging the Center Binder, I get the following result with a gradation. Is there any way to solve this?

```
        g.DrawImage(Resources.Resource.RingBinderTop, new Rectangle((this.Size.Width - 49) / 2, 9, 49, 11));
        g.DrawImage(Resources.Resource.RingBinder, new Rectangle((this.Size.Width - 49) / 2, 20, 49, this.Size.Height - 33));
        g.DrawImage(Resources.Resource.RingBinderBottom, new Rectangle((this.Size.Width - 49) / 2, this.Size.Height - 20, 49, 11));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this was to use FillRectangle with TextureBrush.

```
    g.DrawImage(Resources.Resource.RingBinderTop, new Rectangle((this.Size.Width - 49) / 2, 9, 49, 11));
    g.DrawImage(Resources.Resource.RingBinder, new Rectangle((this.Size.Width - 49) / 2, 20, 49, this.Size.Height - 33));
    g.FillRectangle(new TextureBrush(Resources.Resource.RingBinderBottom), new Rectangle((this.Size.Width - 49) / 2, this.Size.Height - 20, 49, 11));
```

Comment: Dont forget to use below code for texture to start at wanted position. // b.TranslateTransform(p.X, p.Y);

Answer (score 0):

Graphics class draws image in a WinForms application. It flashes the screen during redraw and has poor performance because it depends on GDI. This may be a limitation.

To get a smooth result, use WPF which is DirectX backed.

Comment: Some reference on how to implement on WPF would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not finding the website where I found this, but try the following

```
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
```